# PHP variable binding issue with html from controller for ajax response

Tags: php, html, ajax, laravel

**Controller:**

```
$html = "";
$user_id = 10;
$by = 'By Aaron';
$getLedgerData = "getLedgerData('" . $user_id. "','" . $by . "')";
$html .= "<a onclick=" . $getLedgerData . "></a>"
print_r($html);die; //  result shows: getLedgerData('10','By Aaron')
```

When I passed $html to ajax response and set from there to a respected HTML tag. It will also seem like the above result. But When the HTML page is refreshed then I can see the below error and HTML from inspect element.

```
<a onclick="getLedgerData('10','By" 'Aaron')=""></a>
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token (at 0:1:35)
```

The result should be like this:

```
<a onclick="getLedgerData('10','By Aaron')"></a>
```

I don't know why HTML replaces **'By Arron'** with **'By" 'Arron'**

Comment: You should just be passing the needed details to JS as a JSON response and then building the link on the client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are not wrapping in quote marks in line 4, change to below to add that:

```
$html .= "<a onclick=\"" . $getLedgerData . "\"></a>";
```

Also you might need to change to single quotes this line also:

```
$getLedgerData = 'getLedgerData(\'' . $user_id. '\',\'' . $by . '\')';
```

Comment: @KetanHarsoda No problem, but as commented miken32, the best practice is not to send DOM elements via json, but only needed variables, and then construct html DOM elements in clientside (js).

Comment: Is there any measure drawback if we passed the whole DOM through JSON from the backend? @tokkerbaz

Comment: Well, If there was no deficiency sending DOM via JSON, then your question would not have been created =) The backend needs to just send needed data to clientside, and all DOM manipulations needs to be done clientside. Its not illegal to send DOM =) But just a having a clean code. Every code should be used in their curcimstance, DOM - clientside, logic - backend =) Thats my opinion, you may not be agree with it =)

Comment: I totally agree with you bro! I just wanted to know that is there any speed-related or security-related issues occurring due to this or not. :) By the way, Thanks for your warm support! :)

Comment: No problem @KetanHarsoda, happy to help bro =)